# Mass Action not sending all data

Tags: magento-2.1, adminhtml, grid, massaction

I've created a mass action for my custom grid. i've encountered a weird problem which is when i check all the checkboxes, it won't send any post id data when i try to retrieve it with:

```
$this->getRequest->getParams();
```

but when i don't check all of them, it will send all the data that has been checked, here's my mass action code in xml:

```
<massaction name="listing_massaction">
  <action name="test">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
      <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
          <item name="type" xsi:type="string">test</item>
          <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Test</item>
          <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="namespace_module/test/massTest"/>
      </item>
    </argument>
  </action>
</massaction>
```

MassTest.php:

```
use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Ui\Component\MassAction\Filter;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection;

class MassTest extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{

   public function __construct(
       Context $context,
       Filter $filter,
       \Namespace\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Test\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
   ) {
       $this->filter = $filter;
       $this->_listingProduct = $listingProduct;
       $this->_collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
       parent::__construct($context, $filter);
   }

   public function execute(){
     //$collection = $this->filter->getCollection($this->_collectionFactory->create()); // get your selected collection
     //$collectionSize = $collection->getSize();
     //echo $collectionSize;
     $data = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
     print_r($data['selected']);
     exit;
   }

   /**
    * @param AbstractCollection $collection
    * @return \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect
    */
   protected function massAction(AbstractCollection $collection)
   {

   }

}
```

Comment: Could You please show your MassDelete.php file?

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya i've updated my question

Answer (score 3):

I spent a lot of time trying to understand, what is wrong with my code, and why Magento does not send *selected* parameter with ids in POST request, when mass action is called. Later I found this "feature":

if you have 1 item in list of items, mass action does not send any data. You must have at least 2 items in list, and then *selected* parameter will exists in POST request and will consists of selected ids.

I have it in Magento 2.1.6.

Comment: yes i think magento has their way to minimize post data

Comment: I've run into this issue in 2.1.10. It's incredibly annoying and if it's as designed, it's incredibly short sighted. Any performance improvement gained by minimizing the post data is lost by having to retrieve the filtered collection again. Besides, getting the collection is not working in my case with a custom list.

Comment: Thank you for the time save

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below code for new way to get the filter or selected collection from the list you selected from your grid.

```
<?php 

namespace Namesapce\Modulename\Controller\Adminhtml\Module;

use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

class MassDelete extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action {

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Ui\Component\MassAction\Filter
     */
    protected $filter;

    /**
     * @var \Namesapce\Modulename\Model\ResourceModel\ModuleModel\CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $_collectionFactory;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Ui\Component\MassAction\Filter $filter
     * @param \Namespace\Modulename\Model\ResourceModel\ModuleModel\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Ui\Component\MassAction\Filter $filter,
        \Namespace\Modulename\Model\ResourceModel\ModuleModel\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
    ) {

        $this->filter = $filter;
        $this->_collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $collection = $this->filter->getCollection($this->_collectionFactory->create()); // get your selected collection
        $collectionSize = $collection->getSize();

        foreach ($collection as $item) {
            $item->delete(); // Do the stuff you wann to do
        }

        $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('A total of %1 record(s) have been deleted.', $collectionSize));

        /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
        return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
    }
}
```

Comment: it will retrieve all the data from my table and its the problem because when i create the grid i filter the grid using `<item name="filter_url_params" xsi:type="array">
              <item name="some_id_in_url" xsi:type="boolean">1</item> </item>`

Comment: no it will not as you see `$this->filter` this will filter and give you the selected rows you want.

Comment: well in my grid there are only 4 data, and when i checked all and i print the $collectionSize it shows 6

Comment: @Priyank Seems to be working for me, do you think could you explain how the filter works here ?

Answer (score 0):

Please check it 
**`app/code/Company/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/company_module_grid.xml`**

```
...
<massaction name="listing_massaction">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">company_module_grid.company_module_grid.company_module_columns.ids</item>
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <action name="delete">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="type" xsi:type="string">delete</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete</item>
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="routername/controllername/massDelete"/>
                        <item name="confirm" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete items</item>
                            <item name="message" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Are you sure you wan't to delete selected items?</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </action>
</massaction>
...
```

**Controller File**
**`app/code/Company/Module/Controller/Adminhtml/Controllername/MassDelete.php`**

```
<?php
namespace Company\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Controllername;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Ui\Component\MassAction\Filter;
use Company\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

/**
 * Class MassDisable
 */
class MassDelete  extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    /**
     * @var Filter
     */
    protected $filter;

    /**
     * @var CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $collectionFactory;


    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param Filter $filter
     * @param CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
     */
    public function __construct(Context $context, Filter $filter, CollectionFactory $collectionFactory)
    {
        $this->filter = $filter;
        $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
    /**
     * Execute action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException|\Exception
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $collection = $this->filter->getCollection($this->collectionFactory->create());
        $collectionSize = $collection->getSize();

        foreach ($collection as $item) {
            $item->delete();
        }

        $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('A total of %1 record(s) have been deleted.', $collectionSize));

        /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
        return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
    }
}
```

`Company\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory;` Please add appropriate extension factory class in about file.

Comment: the $collectionSize is still counting more then i checked if i checked it all

Comment: I don't see why retrieving the filtered collection should give the the checked items. It would return all the items in the list, checked or not, wouldn't it?